# Eclipse RCP - Open wordfile using JACOB - error "Failed to write core dump.Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows"

Tags: java, eclipse, ms-word, jacob, minidump

Am quite new to Eclipse [RCP](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html) Java and JACOB(java/COM bridge). I was trying to open a word file(already created "test.docx") from my RCP program. I have used **jacob.jar**(CLASSPATH) and **jacob.ddl**(PATH) for opening the file- I have followed the instructions in this [tutorial](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/33305). But when I run the program, word file pops up but suddenly gets crashed by the following error.

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x7762e005, pid=8552, tid=8136

 JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_66-b18) (build 1.8.0_66-b18)
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.66-b18 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ntdll.dll+0x2e005]

# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

 An error report file with more information is saved as:
 D:\...\Eclipse\eclipse-j2Development-4.5-win32\eclipse\hs_err_pid8552.log

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
  http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
 The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
 See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

I tried several options like changing workspace, deleting `.metadata` folder but I couldn't find a solution. Help will be highly appreciated.

regards

Adrin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys. I found the problem. There was a version miss match. The .dll file I used was older version and some of the functionalities were deprecated.And that made the crash. if anyone using Jacob please refer to [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/?source=typ_redirect) for latest versions. 
Thank you